# trouble with a currency converter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, currency, converters

Im having trouble with this javascript. here is a n example

```
 window.onload = initPage;

var euro;
var convert;

function initPage()
{
    document.getElementById("convertButton").onclick = calcAnswer();
    document.getElementById("conversionType").onchange = calcAnswer();
}

function calcAnswer()
{
    //alert(document.getElementById("conversionType").value);

    var value1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var conversionType = document.getElementById("conversionType").value;
    //alert(conversionType);

    if(var value = document.getElementById("conversionType").value=="polish");
        document.getElementById("answer").value=(value1-32)/9*5;
    else
        document.getElementById("answer").value=value1*9/5+32;
}
```

here is the html

```
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>


  <form name="convert">

Choose which currency you would like to convert to the Euro:
<select id="conversionType">
    <option value="polish">Polish Zloty</option>
    <option value="ukraine">Ukraine Hryvnia</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>

<hr>
      Amount:<input id="amount" type="text" />
<input id="convertButton" type="button" value="Convert->"/>
      To:
<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer" readonly="readonly"/>


</form>
```

im using an old temperature converter and havent changed that part part but even that part is not working.

Comment: I'm having trouble with my car.  help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, these two lines are wrong:

```
document.getElementById("convertButton").onclick = calcAnswer();
document.getElementById("conversionType").onchange = calcAnswer();
```

Change them to:

```
document.getElementById("convertButton").onclick = calcAnswer;
document.getElementById("conversionType").onchange = calcAnswer;
```

You want to assign a function reference to `onclick` and `onchange`, not actually call the function and assign the return value.

Then, fix the `if` statement in `calcAnswer` like this:

```
function calcAnswer()
{
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var conversionType = document.getElementById("conversionType").value;
    var answerElement = document.getElementById("answer");
    //alert(conversionType);

    if(conversionType == "polish") {
        answerElement.value = (amount-32)/9*5;
    } else {
        answerElement.value = amount*9/5+32;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
document.getElementById("convertButton").onclick = calcAnswer;
document.getElementById("conversionType").onchange = calcAnswer;
```

(without the parens)

You just need to reference the function, not execute it.